# вложенные tab's bootstrap

Tags: html, css3, bootstrap

Стандартный код:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="active"><a href="#1" data-toggle="tab">Вкладка 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#2" data-toggle="tab">Вкладка 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content clearfix">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="1">текст 1</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="2">текст 2</div>
</div>
```

Мне требуется, во вкладку 2 сделать еще две суб-вкладки.

Делаю так:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="active"><a href="#1" data-toggle="tab">Вкладка 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#2" data-toggle="tab">Вкладка 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content clearfix">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="1">текст 1</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="2">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li><a href="#3" data-toggle="tab">Суб 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#4" data-toggle="tab">Суб 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    Текст 2
    <div class="tab-pane" id="3">суб текст 1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="4">суб текст 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

При первом клике работает нормально, а когда кликаю на "вкладка 1/2", то суб-вкладки исчезают навсегда.

Как правильно организовать суб-вкладки?

Comment: @Aлександр делается **точно так же**, как и обычные табы

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, как вы читаете доки, но вот я скопировал их функционал и скопипастил то же самое (изменив айдишники) в один из табов. Всё работает.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Вкладка 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Вкладка 2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Вкладка 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">
    текст 1
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2">

    текст 2

    <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#tab21" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Вкладка 2.1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#tab22" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Вкладка 2.2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#tab23" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Вкладка 2.3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab21">текст 2.1</div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab22">текст 2.2</div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab23">текст 2.3</div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3">
    текст 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Aлександр если там не нужен текст - просто не пишите его.